# How to: Wait textfield input instead of keyboard input from terminal JavaFX(JAVA)

Tags: java, input, javafx-2, java.util.scanner, textfield

First of all, I would like to inform you that I have created a Gui application in javafx and I have many pages with its controllers.I manage every objects in Gui(textfields, labels) application with my global variables.

These global variables are identified by database webservice parse method as long as the input is available for the text field and this textfield controls all values.

If I enter "exit" it quits from program.

If I enter "distribution" it enters to distribution page in program.

Initially, I was using terminal keyboard input to put related word to textfield and then Gui acts according to this texfield.In this case I was using keyboard terminal input like ;

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner();

while(true){

String text = scanner.nextLine();

//all my code is available here and works in this "while" infinite loop)
}
```

So I just would like to ask;

As you see my program works in infinite `"while(loop)"` and everytime it checks keyboard input to put it to textfield.

Each turn of a loop stops in `"String text = scanner.nextLine();"` command to get input and it does not let loop to continue next line as long as keyboard input is not available in terminal.

So, I am trying to change this keyboard input from terminal to textfield input from GUI.

So how can ı make this while loop stop and wait for textfield input  like

> String text = scanner.nextLine();

command for keyboard input from terminal

Comment: your question is not clear enough for me! I can't give you an exact answer!! Are trying to get text from your TextField whenever the Enter key is pressed ? 
you can disable your GUI while the textfield is empty, or wait until the enter key is pressed to parse the command from your textField and enable your GUI again. If this is what you are looking for, I can give you an answer/example

Comment: Actually my question is based on how to stop infinite while loop.I was able to do that with keyboard input with scanner method from terminal.But I just disabled this keyboard input from terminal and ı want to apply same type of method to stop while loop and wait for my textfield input in the beginning of this while loop.This while loop should continue ccording to my choice in textfield.